# replace cell with string if row sums zero in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe, and I am trying to replace cells with a string if the entire row is equal to 0 (contains only NaN and or 0).

I want to do this for all but the first column but my loop is not working, its changing all values in the df to 'test'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':['a','b','c','d'],'id': [np.nan, 2, 0, np.nan], 'id1': [np.nan,2,np.nan, np.nan], 'b': [np.nan,1,0, np.nan]})
```

```
for col in df:
    if col != 'a':
        df[~df.sum(axis=1).ne(0)] = 'test'
```

output i want

```
   a    id   id1     b
0  a  test  test  test
1  b     2     2     1
2  c  test  test  test
3  d  test  test  test
```

Comment: A row with values `[2, 5, -7]` also sums to 0 so `sum` might be dangerous if you're looking for all zero/NaN rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass mask for compare columns to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
c = df.columns != 'a'
df.loc[~df.sum(axis=1).ne(0), c] = 'test'
print (df)
   a    id   id1     b
0  a  test  test  test
1  b   2.0   2.0   1.0
2  c  test  test  test
3  d  test  test  test
```

Like @Mustafa Aydın pointed in comments, more safe is compare by `0` with replace `NaN` to `0`:

```
c = df.columns != 'a'
df.loc[~df.fillna(0).ne(0).all(axis=1), c] = 'test'
print (df)
   a    id   id1     b
0  a  test  test  test
1  b   2.0   2.0   1.0
2  c  test  test  test
3  d  test  test  test
```

Working same like:

```
c = df.columns != 'a'
df.loc[df.fillna(0).eq(0).any(axis=1), c] = 'test'
```